# React router V4 with inner views

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, angular-ui-router, react-router

I am coming from Angular background and I am trying create what I know from before with angular's `ui-router`.

I want to create a main template for the app that will have a static sidebar and views that change based on links clicked in the sidebar.

The key is for the sidebar to be static but the views to load dynamically. The tutorials I went though are reloading the nav links on every view and that is not what I am shooting for. Maybe I am missing something but in my mind the sidebar should be static and never reload...

trying to achieve the following with the `react-router`:

```
<article id="my-app">
    <header>
        <h1>Oh my beautiful app!</h1>
    </header>

    <aside>
        <nav>
            <Link to="/"/>
            <Link to="/page1"/>
            <Link to="/page2"/>
        </nav>
    </aside>

    <section><!-- VIEW RENDERED HERE --></section>

    <footer></footer>
</article>
```

If this is not the way it is done with React I would like to know why and how it is done the right way with React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thank you **bunakawaka** for pointing me into the right direction. This was not the solution but pointed me where I needed to go.

Here is the solution....

```
<article id="my-app">
    <header>
        <h1>Oh my beautiful app!</h1>
    </header>

    <aside>
        <nav>
            <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
            <Link to="/account">Account</Link>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </nav>
    </aside>

    <section>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/account" component={Account}/>
                <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
                <Route path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </section>

    <footer></footer>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you expect, but I'm kind of sleepy. lulz.

You can do something like

```
<Router>
   <Route path="/" render={() => <LayoutComponent><MyComponent /></LayoutComponent>} />
</Router>
```

and then in Layout, somewhere in render place

```
{this.props.children}
```